# Automatic cache refresh with Guava

Tags: java, caching, guava

Thanks to this forum ([How to automatically refresh Cache using Google Guava?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11463675/how-to-automatically-refresh-cache-using-google-guava)), I learn about Guava. 
I wanted to ask some information about the above topic ([How to automatically refresh Cache using Google Guava?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11463675/how-to-automatically-refresh-cache-using-google-guava)) but I can't to write comments for questions because my reputation is too low. 
Consequently, I have to create a new topic. Thank you for your understanding.

Seeing this code,

```
LoadingCache<K, V> cache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
        .refreshAfterWrite(15, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
        .maximumSize(100)
        .build(new MyCacheLoader());
```

if one entry A is loaded with her value at least one time,
is really the above code sufficient to reload automatically every 15 minutes the value associated to the key A ?

Of course, as mentioned by Frank, "I override the CacheBuilder.reload(K, V) method in MyCacheLoader so it performs asynchronously."
Or does i have code to add ? If yes, where ?
Thank you very much

PS: JB, the javadoc is perfect but my level in english is low. In fact, the overridden reload of my CacheLoader see if a real reload has to be performed for a key, and if yes, realize a real reload for that key; otherwise do not make a real reload of the cache for that key. And, even in the second case (no real reload), does I have a call of my overridden reload method every 15 minutes ? I think so but am I right ? Thanks

Comment: What is unclear in the javadoc? What does your test show?

Comment: JB, the Java doc is very clear, but my level in english is low.

Comment: JB, the javadoc is perfect but my level in english is low. In fact, the overrided reload of my CacheLoader see if a real reload has to be performed for a key, and if yes, realize a real reload for taht key; otherwise do not make a real reload of the cache for that key. And, even in the second case (no real reload), does i have a call of my overrided relaod method every 15 minutes ? I think so but am i right ? Thanks

Comment: See also [LoadingCache with async loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17456955/loadingcache-with-async-loading)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A `LoadingCache` built with

```
LoadingCache<K, V> cache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
        .refreshAfterWrite(15, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
        .maximumSize(100)
        .build(new MyCacheLoader());
```

will *not* refresh *automatically by itself* an entry every 15 minutes, as the cache does not create threads to do any kind of management (expiring or refreshing entries). If you call `cache.get(someKey)` then call it again 20 minutes later, it will *then* refresh the entry as a consequence of your call, provided the entry has not been evicted due to the `maximumSize` being reached, of course.

I'm not quite sure what you're asking about `CacheLoader::reload` and asynchronicity. If you overrode it, you already added code, didn't you? Hopefully it's not just a call to `super.reload(k, v)`, as that would not be asynchronous. You can complete your question with more details if needed.

However, as mentionned before, the method is *not* called automatically every 15 minutes for any present key, it's only called on demand when an entry is requested again.

Comment: Franck, i will thank you for your answer. You are very skilled. I am learning GUAVA and, for sure, will have certainly others questions. Thank you very much and have a good evening.

Comment: Frank, i want to mark your answer as useful, but i can't because my reputation is too low. Have a nice evening. Bonne soirée.